# Creating in-memory set for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm trying to implement a random chat app in Rails. Basically, you get randomly paired up with another person in a conversation. What I'd like to do is have an in-memory set of "open" conversations. When a new user connects, I'll see if there's a conversation in the set. If there is, then I'll remove the conversation from the set and add the new user to it. Otherwise, I'll create a new conversation with that user and add the conversation to the pool.

I'm thinking of using Redis for this, as it's in memory and has a set data structure. However, most of the Redis with Rails documentation is rather high level and deals with caching/session data. I just want a set data structure that has some way of getting values out atomically. Should I use Redis for this? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: The simpler way is to use a database, this really is not a suitable use for an simple in-memory store. You should be persisting things use ActiveRecord talking to a database of some kind.

Comment: I was doing this in a database, but the query logic is getting quite hairy. Namely, I'm querying for conversations with exactly one membership (conversations has_many memberships) where that membership does not have the same uuid (I'm using uuids in lieu of actual accounts), etc, etc.

Comment: And also, I don't really think this stuff should be persisted. If a conversation isn't being paired up in a few minutes, it should be tossed out of the pool, as the user has most likely gone away.

Comment: If you're using mysql, you can use [memory table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) to create in-memory table. if you're using postgresql, you can create [table space](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) on `/dev/shm`(RAM). In either case, you need database-specific migration.

Comment: The hairy db logic could be shaved quite nicely, unless you have something non-obvious going on in that beard. A trivial optimisation would be to either not have singles in a conversation yet, or to have them marked specifically as open. `Users.where(open: true).first` or `Users.where(convo: null).first` should be quite... hairless.